# Null message body; hope that's ok

Tags: shell-script, cron, ksh, sendmail

I have the following command below as part of a cronjob. When I run the command via cron or at the command line, I get `Null message body; hope that's ok`.

The contents of the email are empty but when I check the `/tmp/sdplogs.out` file it has content in it.

The script `/dproxy/scripts/cleanSDP2xLogs.sh` sends output to the file `/tmp/sdplogs.out`.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ /dproxy/scripts/cleanSDP2xLogs.sh | mail -s 'SDP2.X Prod LogArchiving Report' joeblow@xyz.com < /tmp/sdplogs.out
Null message body; hope that's ok
```

Comment: what is the content of the cleanSDP2xLogs.sh script?

Comment: LOGDIR=/dproxy/logs/was8

find $LOGDIR/scs -name '*app.log*' -mtime +30 | xargs rm -v > /tmp/sdplogs.out 2>&1
find $LOGDIR/sas -name '*app.log*' -mtime +30 | xargs rm -v >> /tmp/sdplogs.out 2>&1

find $LOGDIR/scs -name '*app.log*' -mtime +7 | xargs gzip -v >> /tmp/sdplogs.out 2>&1
find $LOGDIR/sas -name '*app.log*' -mtime +7 | xargs gzip -v >> /tmp/sdplogs.out 2>&1

Comment: @Sandip Put that information in the body of the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 8):

You need to either replace the `|` with `&&` or let the script output the data to stdout and use `|`.

When using `&&`, the `mail` command would only be run when the script exits with 0.

When using the pipe character, your script needs to send the data to stdout so the pipe can pass it on to `mail`.

In what you wrote, the script writes data to the file and `mail` reads from the file **in parallel** — and `mail` ends up reading the file before the script has written anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/dproxy/scripts/cleanSDP2xLogs.sh | mail -s 'SDP2.X Prod LogArchiving Report' joeblow@xyz.com < /tmp/sdplogs.out
```

You are piping output of `cleanSDP2xLogs.sh` to the `mail` command, which I don't think is what you mean. It seems you want to first run `cleanSDP2xLogs.sh` to generate /tmp/sdplogs.out and then feed /tmp/sdplogs.out into the mail command.

If that's the case, just replace `|` with `;` and you should be fine:

```
/dproxy/scripts/cleanSDP2xLogs.sh; mail -s 'SDP2.X Prod LogArchiving Report' joeblow@xyz.com < /tmp/sdplogs.out
```

Comment: That seems to be what the existing answer from over three years ago points to.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do this use `-a` as attachment:

```
/dproxy/scripts/cleanSDP2xLogs.sh
mail -s 'SDP2.X Prod LogArchiving Report' -a /tmp/sdplogs.out joeblow@xyz.com << ""
```

Comment: How do you that the user's `mail` has an `-a` option? What does the `<< ""` do at the end (it looks like the start of a here-document), did you mean `<<<""` (a here-string)?